# how to add a checker and a warning to TextField

Tags: flutter, dart

### Here's the code I want to add the error warning and the qualify checker

```
TextField(
  controller: emailController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'name@example.com',
    labelText: 'Email',
    // icon: Icon(Icons.mail),
    suffixIcon: emailController.text.isEmpty
        ? Container(width: 0)
        : IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.close),
            onPressed: () => emailController.clear(),
          ),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    focusColor: Colors.red
  ),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
  // autofocus: true,
),
```

---

How to make the error warning appeared if the person havent inserted the @gmail.com
[Error Msg looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0xVS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Form()` widget with `TextFormField()` and inside `TextFormField()`

add `validator(val){ // you qualify checker }` and then you can call

`_key.currentState.validate()` on button click to validate your email.

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
final GlobalKey<FormState> _key = GlobalKey(); 

var emailController = TextEditingController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
        height:150,
        child: Column(
          children:[
            Form(
                key: _key,
                child:TextFormField(
                  controller: emailController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'name@example.com',
                      labelText: 'Email',
                      // icon: Icon(Icons.mail),
                      suffixIcon: emailController.text.isEmpty
                          ? Container(width: 0)
                          : IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                        onPressed: () => emailController.clear(),
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      focusColor: Colors.red
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                  // autofocus: true,
                  onFieldSubmitted: (val){
                    _key.currentState!.validate();
                  },
                  validator: (val){
                    if(!val!.contains("@")){
                      return "invalid email";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                )
            ),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
              _key.currentState.validate();
            }, child: Text("Check"),)
          ],
        ),
      );
     }
    }
```

Comment: where's _key come from?

Comment: Its global key for form check line no. 2 in code

Comment: 'This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled' i got this error

Comment: `if(!val!.contains("@"))` remove `!` after val and from `_key.currentState!.validate();` too that will fix it.